# Conjugation of 'shall' in Early Modern English

Tags: early-modern-english, conjugation

In Shakespeare's Macbeth, the Third Witch says to Banquo: "Thou shalt get kings, though thou be none" (1.3.65); if I want to quote that line and write it in the third person singular, how should I conjugate the verbs "shall" and "be" correctly?

Comment: In reported speech: the witch said he would get kings, though he was none.

Answer (score 4):

Shall is an auxiliary verb, so its conjugation follows the rules of *shall/will/can/may/should/would/could/might* and is different from regular verbs. The only change from the base form is for second person singular:

> *I shall, thou shalt, he shall, we/you/they shall*.

(And you could have figured this out for yourself; look in Shakespeare, e.g. *That henceforth he shall trouble us no more.*)

And the subjunctive *be* is the same for all subjects. So:

> He shall get kings, though he be none.